# How to delete the auto generated copy ctor when you have a templated ctor with same pattern

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, constructor

I am having a problem with the auto generated copy ctor.  I understand that one is being generated even though I have a ctor with the same pattern, because my ctor is templated and thus not a copy ctor.  So I think A and B are acting as expected (secondary question 1: Are A and B really supposed to insidiously generate a bogus copy ctor?).  Anyway when I make a duplicate version of my ctor, sans const (C), the auto generated copy ctor doesn't get called.  This is my fix to my problem, but it smells bad (2ndary 2: why does const make the difference?  Shouldn't the compiler be able to promote to const to use my ctor?).  I would prefer (D) over (C), but even though the cast looks right, the auto generated copy ctor gets called (2ndary 3: why is my cast failing?).  I don't want to have to add a dummy parameter (E) just to be able to call the correct ctor (2ndary4: why does the cast work here?).

I feel like I should be able to delete the auto generated copy ctor (F & G), but I can't figure out how.  So my question is.  How to delete the auto generated copy ctor when you have a templated ctor with the same pattern?

```
// This example calls the auto generated copy ctor
template <int X> class A {
    int m_n;
public:
    A(int n) : m_n(n) { }
    template <int X1> A(const A<X1>& r) :  m_n(10) { }
};

// This example calls the auto generated copy ctor
template <int X> class B {
    int m_n;
public:
    B(int n) : m_n(n) { }
    template <int X1> B(const B<X1>& r, int n=10) : m_n(n) { }
};

// This example calls my ctor
template <int X> class C {
    int m_n;
public:
    C(int n) : m_n(n) { }
    template <int X1> C(const C<X1>& r) : m_n(10) { }
    template <int X1> C(C<X1>& r) : m_n(10) { }
};

// This example calls the auto generated copy ctor
template <int X> class D {
    int m_n;
public:
    D(int n) : m_n(n) { }
    template <int X1> D(const D<X1>& r) : m_n(10) { }
    template <int X1> D(D<X1>& r) : D(const_cast<const D<X1>&>(r)) { }
};

// This example calls ctor
template <int X> class E {
    int m_n;
public:
    E(int n) : m_n(n) { }
    template <int X1> E(const E<X1>& r, int n=10) : m_n(n) { }
    template <int X1> E(E<X1>& r) : E(r, 10) { }
};

// This example fails to compile
template <int X> class F {
    int m_n;
public:
    F(int n) : m_n(n) { }
    template <int X1> F(const F<X1>& r) : m_n(10) { }
    F<X>(F<X>& r) = delete;
};

// This example fails to compile
template <int X> class G {
    int m_n;
public:
    G(int n) : m_n(n) { }
    template <int X1> G(const G<X1>& r) : m_n(10) { }
    template <int X1> G(G<X1>& r) = delete;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A<1> a1(1);  // m_n = 1
    A<1> a2(a1); // !FAIL! m_n = 1, NOT 10

    B<1> b1(1);  // m_n = 1
    B<1> b2(b1); // !FAIL! m_n = 1, NOT 10

    C<1> c1(1);  // m_n = 1
    C<1> c2(c1); // m_n = 10

    D<1> d1(1);  // m_n = 1
    D<1> d2(d1); // !FAIL! m_n = 1, NOT 10

    E<1> e1(1);  // m_n = 1
    E<1> e2(e1); // m_n = 10

    F<1> f1(1);  // m_n = 1
    //F<1> f2(f1); // wont compile, referencing deleted function

    G<1> g1(1);  // m_n = 1
    //G<1> g2(g1); // wont compile, referencing deleted function
}
```

Comment: `template <int X1> A(const A<X1>& r) :  m_n(10) { }` -> this is **not** a copy constructor.

Comment: Simple templated constructor.

Comment: Ahhh.  Ok.  Any idea how to delete the default copy ctor?

Comment: You should not delete it, you should define it.

Comment: That works.  Is there any way to call my templated ctor from my copy ctor?

Comment: There is no way in C++ to directly set template arguments to templated constructor. You can create a templated class method with the templated constructor's functionality and call it in both constructors. Or you can [set template argument indirectly with an auxiliary constructor's parameter](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/546c5a62e6d1110c) but this technique requires C++11 delegating constructors support (VS 2012 lacks of it).

Comment: if you make your comment the answer, ill accept it

Comment: [Done.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33137229/3043539)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not delete a copy constructor, you should define it instead. If you want to avoid code duplication there are two ways (unfortunately you can't directly set template arguments to a templated constructor in C++):

1. You can create a templated class method with the templated constructor's functionality and call it in both constructors. This way is not good enough because you can't use initializer list in such method .
2. You can set a template argument indirectly with an auxiliary constructor's parameter. But this technique requires C++11 delegating constructors support and unfortunately VS 2012 lacks of it (you may use Visual C++ 2012 November CTP as a temporary solution).

See code example below:

```
template <class T>
struct Identity{};

template <class T>
struct S
{
    S() = default;

    template <class U>
    S(const S<U>&, Identity<U> = {})
    {
        std::cout << "Templated constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    S(const S<T>& s) : S(s, Identity<T>{})
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

// ...

S<int> s1;
S<int> s2(s1);
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/546c5a62e6d1110c)

Comment: You can make a default dummy parameter without using a template struct.  template <class U> S(const S<U>&, bool fDummy=false).  Why did you use a templated struct in your method?

Comment: @johnnycrash You may want to have `S::S(const S<SomeType>& s, bool);` constructor and then such simple solution doesn't work. But you are right my solution is too complicated for such simple case.

Comment: one other question... how do you insert the live demo button like that?

Comment: @johnnycrash Press *edit* button under the answer and you will see an unformatted source code of it. Such button is inserted with a `kbd` html tag.

Comment: I must have been tired.  I hit edit before i asked you and then looked at the "resulting" text instead of the editable text.  idiot...